# Calculate certainty of Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: probability, montecarlo

Let's say that we use the Monte Carlo method to estimate the area of an object, in the exact same way you'd [use it to estimate the value of π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method#Overview).

Now, let's say we want to calculate the certainty of our simulation result. We've cast *n* samples, *m* of which landed inside the object, so the area of the object is approximately *m*/*n* of the total sampled area. We would like to make a statement such as:

*"We are 99% certain that the area of the object is between a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub>."*

How can we calculate a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> above (given *n*, *m*, total area, and the desired certainty)?

Here is a program which attempts to estimate this bound numerically. Here the samples are points in [0,1), and the object is the segment [0.25,0.75). It prints a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub> for 50%, 90%, and 99%, for a range of sample counts:

```
import std.algorithm;
import std.random;
import std.range;
import std.stdio;

void main()
{
    foreach (numSamples; iota(0, 1000+1, 100).filter!(n => n > 0))
    {
        auto samples = new double[numSamples];
        enum objectStart = 0.25;
        enum objectEnd   = 0.75;

        enum numTotalSamples = 10_000_000;
        auto numSizes = numTotalSamples / numSamples;
        auto sizes = new double[numSizes];
        foreach (ref size; sizes)
        {
            size_t numHits;
            foreach (i; 0 .. numSamples)
            {
                auto sample = uniform01!double;
                if (sample >= objectStart && sample < objectEnd)
                    numHits++;
            }

            size = 1.0 / numSamples * numHits;
        }

        sizes.sort;
        writef("%d samples:", numSamples);
        foreach (certainty; [50, 90, 99])
        {
            auto centerDist = numSizes * certainty / 100 / 2;
            auto startPos = numSizes / 2 - centerDist;
            auto endPos   = numSizes / 2 + centerDist;
            writef("\t%.5f..%.5f", sizes[startPos], sizes[endPos]);
        }
        writeln;
    }
}
```

([Run it online](https://run.dlang.io/is/lM3j87).) It outputs:

```
//                     50%                 90%                 99%
100 samples:    0.47000..0.53000    0.42000..0.58000    0.37000..0.63000
200 samples:    0.47500..0.52500    0.44500..0.56000    0.41000..0.59000
300 samples:    0.48000..0.52000    0.45333..0.54667    0.42667..0.57333
400 samples:    0.48250..0.51750    0.46000..0.54250    0.43500..0.56500
500 samples:    0.48600..0.51600    0.46400..0.53800    0.44200..0.55800
600 samples:    0.48667..0.51333    0.46667..0.53333    0.44833..0.55167
700 samples:    0.48714..0.51286    0.46857..0.53143    0.45000..0.54857
800 samples:    0.48750..0.51250    0.47125..0.53000    0.45375..0.54625
900 samples:    0.48889..0.51111    0.47222..0.52667    0.45778..0.54111
1000 samples:   0.48900..0.51000    0.47400..0.52500    0.45800..0.53900
```

Is it possible to precisely calculate these numbers instead?

(Context: I'd like to add something like "±X.Y GB with 99% certainty" to btdu)

Comment: Is this question suitable for stats.stackexchange.com? I know much less about statistics than the level of the average question there.

Comment: Removed the [d] tag added by @Progman. Though my illustration program is written in D, the question is language-agnostic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, with question being language agnostic, here is the illustration how to do error estimation with Monte-Carlo.

Suppose, you want to compute integral

I = S<sub>0</sub><sup>1</sup> f(x) dx

where f(x) is simple polynomial function

f(x) = x<sup>n</sup>

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68984617/build-n-distribution-of-monte-carlo-box-method-in-python/68990820#68990820) is the illustration of the calculations.

For that you have to compute not only mean value, but standard deviation as well.

Then, knowing that Monte Carlo error is going down as inverse square root of number of samples, computing confidence interval is simple

Code, Python 3.7, Windows 10 x64

```
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng()

N = 100000

n = 2

def f(x):
    return np.power(x, n)

sample = f(rng.random(N)) # N samples of the function

m = np.mean(sample)        # mean value of the sample, approaching integral value as N->∞
s = np.std(sample, ddof=1) # standard deviation with Bessel correction

e = s / np.sqrt(N) # Monte Carlo error decreases as inverse square root

t = 2.576 # For 99% confidence interval, we should take 2.58 sigma, per Gaussian distribution
#t = 3.00 # For 99.7% confidence interval, we should take 3 sigma, per Gaussian distribution

print(f'True integral value is {1.0/(1.0+n)}')
print(f'Computed integral value is in the range [{m-t*e}...{m+t*e}] with 99% confidence')
```

will print something like

```
True integral value is 0.3333333333333333
Computed integral value is in the range 
[0.33141772204489295...0.3362795491124624] with 99% confidence
```

You could use Z-score table, line [this one](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch08-int.html) along the lines, to print table you want. You could vary N to get desired N dependency

```
zscore = {'50%': 0.674, '80%': 1.282, '90%': 1.645, '95%': 1.960, '98%': 2.326, '99%': 2.576, '99.7%': 3.0}
for c, z in zscore.items():
    print(f'Computed integral value is in the range [{m-z*e}...{m+z*e}] with {c} confidence')
```

Comment: @VladimirPanteleev Just to put things in perspective, for small number of samples (say, less than 100) you'd have to use t-score (t-distribution based confidence interval) instead of z-score (Gaussian based confidence interval). It will make interval a bit larger

Comment: BruceET suggests Agresti-Coull confidence intervals for small n on Cross Validated. What would be the equivalent algorithm for t-score?

Comment: Well A-C is for binomial ratios, IIRC. What I was talking about is generic approach to the linear Monte Carlo. When desired value is computed as mean of some random sample, no matter how samples are generated. When N is small and it matters, then we have to take it into account, this is when we use t-distribution with dof=N-1. General formula would be m+-z(N, c)*e(N). When N is large we assume it is infinity, t-distribution becomes gaussian, and z(N, c) would only depends on confidence, not N. Not true for small N, you have to have it both in error and score.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Severin's answer, here is the code to calculate the values as stated in the question:

```py
def calculate_error(n, m, z):
    p = m / n
    std_dev = (p * (1 - p)) ** 0.5 # Standard deviation of Bernoulli variable

    error = std_dev / n ** 0.5 # Monte Carlo error decreases as inverse square root
    return (mean - z * error, mean + z * error)

n = 1000
z = 2.576  # For 99% confidence interval, we should take 2.58 sigma, per Gaussian distribution
print(calculate_error(n, n * 0.5, z))
```